# How can I create a ellipse gradient on flat plane?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I need to create a ellipse gradient to be used as a background in a animation but all I managed to do so far is this circle it works great but no matter what I try I cant change the shape of it.
[image: My attempt]

[image: Nodes used]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Gradient Texture* with *Generated Coordinates* will do it in a way that scales to the size of the object, but you need to do a couple of operations on the coordinate space first.

The *Subtract* and *Scale* nodes here are *Vector Math* nodes.  The *Mapping* node then controls the size and position of the gradient.

[image]

[image]